# Running Trac 0.12 and Agilo/Trac 0.11.7 on same server

Tags: trac

I am running Trac 0.12 for day to day SCM and trying to install Agilo
on the same server for evaluation purposes.

After discovering that Agilo does not run on Trac 0.12, I tried to
install 0.11.7 alongside my existing 0.12 installation, using
instructions found at:

http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracMultipleVersions

While I did finally get Agilo up and running, I seem to have corrupted
my Trac 0.12 installation in the process. It's now looking for
resources in:

/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.11.7-py2.4.egg

which is doubly confusing to me, because I thought it would now be
looking in:

/var/trac-0.12/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg

due to using multitrac, or at least:

/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12-py2.4.egg

Since that was the location I assume it must have been using before I
started messing with Agilo.

Can anyone tell me how to get my Trac 0.12 installation to look once
more in the proper site-packages directory?

Answer (score 1):

(Better late than never :)

You should install each Trac version in its own [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). This ensures that they are independent.